# Are the interactive methods of credential gathering listed here actually secure, since they dont store the credentials on disk?

Tags: windows-server, powershell, putty

I found an article about different ways to collect and pass credentials in powershell.  The author states that some of these methods are 100% secure (which is obviously an exaderation) but for purposes of running a short interactive powershell script that passes a username and password to putty or plink to send a command over ssh on Windows Server; apart from also signing the script isn't that about as secure as it gets without installing anything else?

Do the credentials captured have to be scrambled and deleted from memory somehow?

http://dennisspan.com/encrypting-passwords-in-a-powershell-script/